# Can't get selected values of dynamically created Select List list to objects in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I am trying to assing the selected values of Select lists to fields in a complex object list in a loop but its creating new instances of the objects with the selected value and overwriting the existing objects. Tried adding inputs for other fields but it doesnt copy complex variables and leaves them null or empty again.

I have a list of Ball objects with a string id, integer weight value and a dictionary of Color objects and boolean value(I will also use that dictionary for checkboxes). I am initializing the list and dictionary and creating Select Lists in a foreach loop with index. When I submit via Save button I expect to fill the *SelectedColorId* field of the current Ball object with the selected *colorId* but it creates a new Ball object with SelectedColorId field only and others null. I tried copying other values with input tags but still couldnt get the complex objects like *availableColors* dictionary.

How can I assing the selected values to existing objects field without using js or jquery?

[page view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMEGW.png)

[values after submitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSLPO.png)

```
public class Color
{
    private string id;
    private string name;

    public Color(string id, string name)
    {
        this.Id = id; //color-black
        this.Name = name; //black
    }

    public string Id { get => id; set => id = value; }
    public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }
}

 public class Ball
{
    private string id; //smallBall
    private Dictionary<Color, bool> availableColors;
    private string selectedColorId; //color-red
    private int weight; //1

    public Ball() { }

    public Ball(string id, Dictionary<Color, bool> availableColors, int weight)
    {
        Id = id;
        AvailableColors = availableColors;
        SelectedColorId = "";
        Weight = weight;
    }

    public string Id { get => id; set => id = value; }
    public Dictionary<Color, bool> AvailableColors { get => availableColors; set => availableColors = value; }
    public string SelectedColorId { get => selectedColorId; set => selectedColorId = value; }
    public int Weight { get => weight; set => weight = value; }
}
```

my .Cshtml.cs file:

```
[BindProperties]
public class SelectBindingTestModel : PageModel
{
    private List<Ball> balls;

    public List<Ball> Balls { get => balls; set => balls = value; }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        if (Balls == null)
        {
            Balls = new List<Ball>();                
            Balls.Add(new Ball("smallBall", new Dictionary<Color, bool>() {
                { new Color("color-black", "black"), true },
                { new Color("color-red", "red"), true },
                { new Color("color-white", "white"), true },
                { new Color("color-blue", "blue"), true }} , 1));

            Balls.Add(new Ball("mediumBall", new Dictionary<Color, bool>() {
                { new Color("color-blue", "blue"), true },
                { new Color("color-yellow", "yellow"), true },
                { new Color("color-khaki", "khaki"), true }}, 2));

            Balls.Add(new Ball("largeBall", new Dictionary<Color, bool>() {
                { new Color("color-brown", "brown"), true },
                { new Color("color-red", "red"), true },
                { new Color("color-green", "green"), true },
                { new Color("color-pink", "pink"), true }} , 3));
        }                
        return Page();
    }

    public IActionResult OnPostConfirm()
    {
        return Page();
    }
}
```

and .Cshtml file:

```
<p>Test page for binding Select items</p>
<form method="post">
<div class="row">
    @{
        int i = 0;
    }
    @foreach (Ball ball in @Model.Balls)
    {
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="text-align:center;">
            <label class="form-check-label">@ball.Id</label>
            <select class="form-control form-control-sm" asp-for="Balls[i].SelectedColorId" asp-items="@new SelectList(ball.AvailableColors.Keys.ToList(), nameof(Color.Id), nameof(Color.Name))" href="#">
                <option value="" disabled>Select Color</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        i++;
    }
</div>
<br />
<div class="row">
    <div class="dz-button" mt-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" asp-page-handler="Confirm" id="Confirm">Save</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `When I submit via Save button ... creates a new Ball object with SelectedColorId field only and others null.` Do you mean you don't want to create the Ball object? And you want to use a string array or dictionary? Generally, when submit the form, the model binding will bind the property value based on the name attribute. So, if you don't wan to create the Ball object, you can create a Page model property to receive the data, refer to [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7n2rC.gif). Besides, if you want to use complex objects like dictionary, you can use custom model binder.

Comment: Thanks for the gif. It works fine but I would prefer a more elegant way if possible. I mean I would like to assign the value to the existing objects field like `Balls[i].SelectedColorId ` as I thought asp-for would do it but it doesnt. I already have a smallBall object and I want the selected value to go to its *SelectedColorId* field directly. Is that possible? I think its asp-for that creates a new instance of the object instead of taking `Balls[i]` as reference object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

> my expectation is to assing it to smallBall which already has values
> in its other fields

For other fields, such as the Id and weight property, you can use a hidden field to store the value in the Form.

Code like this:

```
@foreach (Ball ball in @Model.Balls)
{
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="text-align:center;">
        <label class="form-check-label">@ball.Id</label>

        <input type="hidden" name='Balls[@i].Id' value="@Model.Balls[i].Id" >

        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" asp-for="Balls[i].SelectedColorId" 
            asp-items="@new SelectList(ball.AvailableColors.Keys.ToList(), nameof(Color.Id).ToString(), nameof(Color.Name))" href="#">
            <option value="" disabled>Select Color</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    i++;
}
```

But to the availableColors dictionary, I suggest you could create a data repository to store them, then, **in the post method**, you can query the data repository and according to the Ball Id to get the availableColors dictionary. Instead of transfer them via form.

The result like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, I did that with [BindProperties] on top of class to bind all properties. and my problem is exactly what happens on your gif. all other fields on those balls in Balls list are null. my expectation is to assing it to smallBall which already has values in its other fields. 
"The asp-for attribute normally populate id and name of the specified HTML attribute for the display expression name. It can assign attribute value based on the model data to the HTML attribute." couldnt get this part

Comment: @Işbara Han, I have update the reply and use the hidden field to store other fields, you can check it. To the availableColors dictionary, I suggest you could create a data repository to store them, if you still want to transfer them via the Form, you need to use for/foreach loop to loo through the dictionary and then use hidden field to store the value, after that you can submit them via the form.

Comment: thanks for the help, I think I'll go with *selectedColors* array for now. but I'll check your latest suggestion for improvements for later on.